# Blur Foreground

Tags: camera, blur

So, I made this outdoor project and I'm trying to blur the grass that peaks in the foreground, but controlling the depth of field and/or focus of the camera doesn't help me at all.
[image: Actual render]

[image]

Comment: Change the *viewport shading* type from *Material* to **Rendered** to see the results.

Comment: The upper picture is the rendered image

Comment: The Size option is set to 0, which means no bluring afaik if using Radius mode for aperture. Either increase it or change it to F-Stop and decrease (by default 5.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

**Focal point:**

Use **Empty** object as a **Focus** to better control **DOF**. Just place it where you want to have sharp spot and it's done.

**Matching Viewport Preview with Render:**

To match both views you need to use **F-stop** values for both **Aperture** and **Viewport** also you need to check **High Quality**. And lastly turn on **Depth Of Field** under **Shading** tab (<kbd>N</kbd> to open/close **Properties Region**).

**Notes:**

Check your **Focal Length** and **F-stop** Values as they are crucial for DOF. Lower **F-stop** value will give you shallow DOF (more blur), higher **Focal Length** will also give you more blur but it will distort perspective.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!
Had problems with a simple empty, so had to create an empty cube, make the borders coincide with the shape of the building, excluding the grass, played a little with tweaking and obtained what I wanted. 
Really really helpful! :)

Comment: @ChristianTriolo To add Empty press Shift+A > Empty > Plain Axes

Comment: @Lincoln are you using Cycles renderer and/or have active camera in the scene?